# display number of consecutive frames in loop captured by video

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, opencv

I am trying to put number of frames which are taken from a video in a loop.I want to display that frames in sequence an after that I want to subtract it using opencv 2.3.

My problem is that I am not able to know where function is not called.

here is my code below:

using namespace cv;

```
  void loadImage(IplImage *image, int number)

  {
    // Store path to directory
    char filename[100];
    strcpy(filename, "S:\FINAL PROJECT ABSTRACT\images 1");

 char *frame;

// Convert integer to char    
char frameNo[10];
//sprintf(frame, "%0.3i", number);

// Combine to generate path
  strcat(filename, frameNo);
  strcat(filename, ".jpg");

// Use path to load image
  image = cvLoadImage(filename);
 }

  int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){

  IplImage *im=0;
  int nImages = 6;
  for (int i = 0; i < nImages; ++i)
 {


  loadImage(im, i);

  char filename[100];
  strcpy(filename, "images 1");

  char frameNo[10];
   sprintf(frameNo, "%03i", i);

  strcat(filename, frameNo);
  strcat(filename, ".jpg");


IplImage *im = cvLoadImage(filename,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
cvNamedWindow("pic");
cvShowImage("pic",im);
cvWaitKey();

}

}

//}
```

I am not getting any error in build.bt while debugging it shows:-
Unhandled exception at 0x77db15de in loop of frames.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.

At 
 strcat(filename, frameNo);
   strcat(filename, ".jpg");
this point some error is there..

Comment: You have commented out the initialisation of `frameNo`, so `strcat()`ing it a line later won't work.

Comment: hi I have commented out if beacuse giving me the error.it is stuck at this point only:sprintf(frame, "%0.3i", number); So not ble to understand it.pls guide me.

Comment: the '.' in that formatting string probably isn't helping.

Comment: thanx but can you suggest me any solution for that.can you be specific? i am not able to get the exact problem...thanx.

Comment: Use a valid formatting string? You use `%03i` elsewhere, without the '.' - If you have a specific error message you don't understand, you should post that. If you take stuff out until it crashes and then post the result, it's hard to help.

Comment: Ah, 'frame' isn't actually initialised either - you need a char buffer to print into. Looks like you mean to use 'frameNo', but have added an extra pointer for no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string handling is pretty confused. It's not clear exactly what path you're trying to generate.

You can replace most of your path generation with a single `sprintf()`

```
char filename[100];
sprintf(filename, "S:\\FINAL PROJECT ABSTRACT\\images 1%03i.jpg",number);
image = cvLoadImage(filename);
```

(100 chars seems somewhat arbitrary - and potentially a bit short)

No idea if that's the right string for your image paths, you were trying to insert a '.' in there, so I don't know what your real file paths look like.

However having loaded the image inside the `loadImage()` function, you then seem to do the exact same thing in `main()` (throw away the image you've just loaded, generate another path, and then load that instead). So I doubt this is going to work even when you fix the string handling.

Comment: hey..thanx for this help.Now I am getting loadImage() function error.I am trying to calll the fucntion outside for loop.here is my modified code: